# Is Postgres unnecessarily typecasting JSON key from jsonb column to text again?

Tags: postgresql

I created a `view` in postgres using the below query

```
    SELECT
        JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
            'street', t.data->'address'->>'street',
            'area', t.data->'address'->>'area',
            'displayLocation', t.data->'address'->>'display_location',
            'postalCode', t.data->'address'->>'postal_code'
        ) AS address
    FROM true_humans t;
```

After creating the view I used the command `\d+ true_humans_view` in my psql, to see the query of the view.
Here is the result of the `\d+` command,

```
      SELECT
        json_build_object(
                   'street', (t.data -> 'address'::text) ->> 'street'::text, 
                   'area', (t.data -> 'address'::text) ->> 'area'::text, 
                   'displayLocation', (t.data -> 'address'::text) ->> 'display_location'::text,                                                          
                    'postalCode', (t.data -> 'address'::text) ->> 'postal_code'::text
        ) AS address
    FROM true_humans t;
```

Why does Postgres do 'address'::text this typecasting? Please help me understand Postgres behaviour.

Comment: What type do you think the literal `'address'` is? What type do you think the literal `'2020-03-31'` is? If you wanted to be clear about what type each was intended to be, what would be a convenient way to specify that?

Comment: "*Is Postgres unnecessarily is typecasting*" - no, it isn't

Comment: @RichardHuxton 'address'  is a string and '2020-03-31' could be DateTime. But all soon keys should be string, isn't it? So why typecast it again, I am still not clear.

Comment: A quoted literal can't be both types at the same time can it? Its type is effectively "unknown quoted thing" and it will be interpreted as a particular type depending on context. In this case you know you want text and so does PostgreSQL. It is being explicit about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consolidating answer to this question from the comments:

What type do you think the literal 'address' is? What type do you think the literal '2020-03-31' is? If you wanted to be clear about what type each was intended to be, what would be a convenient way to specify that?

A quoted literal can't be both types at the same time, can it? Its type is effectively "unknown quoted thing" and it will be interpreted as a particular type depending on the context. In this case, you know you want to text and so does PostgreSQL. It is being explicit about that.

Thanks, Richard Huxton.